# Sum arrays with Numba and CUDA

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

I have just started learning how to program with Numba and CUDA, so this code may be very wrong, but I don't understand why it's not working. I am trying to sum N different arrays, whose content depends on another array. Showing the code is maybe better than this explanation:

```py
import numba as nb
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
from math import exp, ceil

t0s = np.array([2.5,6.7,8.1,9.6,10.5])
threadsperblock = 32
blockspergrid = ceil(t0s.shape[0] / threadsperblock)

time = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
waveform = np.zeros_like(time)
total_waveform = np.zeros_like(waveform)

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def current(waveform, time, t0):
    for i in range(waveform.shape[0]):
        if time[i] > t0:
            waveform[i] = 0
        else:
            waveform[i] = exp(time[i]-t0)

@cuda.jit
def total(time, waveform, total_waveform, t0s):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < t0s.shape[0]:
        current(waveform, time, t0s[i]) 
        for j in range(total_waveform.shape[0]):
            total_waveform[j] += waveform[j]

total[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](time, waveform, total_waveform, t0s)
```

Unfortunately, `total_waveform` contains just the first waveform (it's like it stops after the first element of `t0s`) and I really don't understand why. Help! :)

Comment: suggestions: 1. define what you expect for "correct" results, and also what results you are getting  2.  Break your kernel code into 2 kernels. one that does just the `current` function, followed by one that does just the for loop in your `total` kernel.  Do you get the desired result?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My correct result would be an array containing 5 rising exponential curves, each one ending at `t0s[i]`. However I get only one ending at `t0s[0]`. Could you elaborate more about doing 2 kernels? In my understanding, in order to do that, I would need to instantiate the memory for storing `current` output, but I am only interested in the sum, so I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the posted code and this comment:

> My correct result would be an array containing 5 rising exponential curves, each one ending at `t0s[i]`

it appears you could vastly simplify the code and get the desired result assuming you actually mean

> My correct result would be an array containing **the sum of** 5 rising exponential curves , each one ending at `t0s[i]`.

as while each curve approaches zero at small t when t0 is large, each curve is always non zero on [0, t0) for all t0 > 0. If I haven't misunderstood your intentions and code, could you:

1. Change `current` to be a scalar function
2. Eliminate `waveform` all together, it is an intermediate result which you do not need to store
3. Change the parallelisation strategy so that each thread calculates just one time point  in the output (i.e. reverse the order of the loops from your original code). If you do that, there are no memory races or synchronization issues.

If you do those three things, you would get something like this:

```
$ cat wavegoodbye.py 
import numba as nb
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
from math import exp, ceil

t0s = np.array([2.5,6.7,8.1,9.6,10.5])
time = np.linspace(0,10,2000)

total_waveform = np.zeros_like(time)

threadsperblock = 32
blockspergrid = ceil(total_waveform.shape[0] / threadsperblock)

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def current(time, t0):
    if time > t0:
       waveform = 0
    else:
       waveform = exp(time-t0)

    return waveform

@cuda.jit
def total(time, total_waveform, t0s):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < total_waveform.shape[0]:
        for j in range(t0s.shape[0]):
            total_waveform[i] += current(time[i], t0s[j]) 

total[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](time, total_waveform, t0s)
```

which does this:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.11.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %run wavegoodbye.py                                                                                                                          

In [2]: import pylab as pl                                                                                                                           

In [3]: pl.plot(time, total_waveform)
```

[image]

I presume that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes! That works! However I am still not sure why my original code wasn't working. Everything after `if i < t0s.shape[0]:` runs in a different thread right? Why do I encounter a race condition/synchronization issue?

Comment: In your original code you have multiple threads simultaneously trying to update total_waveform  in lock step. Only one thread will win That is a memory race. Even if that were not the case, reversing the order of the loop will run more threads and expose much more parallelism. Having 1000 threads doing 5 calculations each in parallel will be much faster than 5 threads doing 1000 calculations each in parallel